# Windows loses all audio if I lower volume to 0

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

I have this issue where Windows 10 will vanish/disable/not play anything via headphones if I lower volume while wearing headphones to 0. The issue is when I raise volume again, it does not have any sound at any volume. This does not affect sound without headphones (aka I can hear if headphones aren't plugged in.)

Only solution I have so far is a full PC restart. Which is impractical.

How do I fix it?

Comment: *:scratches head:* I think you need to rewrite your question more clearly.  It sounds like you are lowering you volume to 0, in which you *shouldnt* here anything.  Are you raising it again and nothing is happening?

Comment: @Keltari Right, thanks. Kinda late and I didn't notice.

Comment: Exactly as you said, raising it and nothing happens.

Comment: out of curiosity, what type of headphone connector?  3.5mm jack, or USB?

Comment: 3.5MM Jack is the headphone connector.

Comment: I havent *heard* (pun intended) of such an issue before.  I highly doubt it is a Windows issue.  It *sounds* (pun intended) more like a driver issue.  Make sure you have the latest audio driver.

Comment: Strangely enough this happened after updating drivers? But I will try and reinstall the manufacturer ones and see if that helps.

Comment: What is the manufacturer / model of headphones you are using?

Answer (score 0):

For future people, it seems that it was caused by updating drivers that are not supported. I resolved this by going to manufacturer site and getting those drivers. Installed them and error went away.